# Python check if the line contains any specific or exact words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find the method for checking the line; if it contains pronouns such as he, she, it, or they, then print it's not a statement. I've tried the function `__contains__`. It does work for my 3rd line, but it doesn't work well for the 4th line (Hershey's has "she"). I'm desperate to find online what methods would work well in this problem.

```py
if line.lower().__contains__("she"):
    print(line," NOT A STATEMENT")
```

Right below is the text file.

```
Strawberries are fruit.
Do you like grape jelly?
She sings well.
Hershey's chocolate is delicious
```

Comment: It's better not to use magic methods directly, use `in` instead. `if "she" in line.lower()`

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary what if I have multiple conditions?

Comment: Then you use `and` between conditions.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary still checking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your word by splitting statement with blank character.

Please change your code as a below.

```
if(("she") in line.lower().strip(",.!;:").split()):
   print(line, " NOT A STATEMENT")
```

Comment: I think a strip operation here is also needed. because `"she,"` and `"she."` doesn't pass that check.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I added strip() function for possible special characters.

Comment: Great, now as the OP asked for several pronouns(he, she, they, it) , you need to have a for loop to check each of them.

Answer (score 1):

### Regex version

One way of doing it is using Regex. `\b` is the key here. it's a word boundary.

```py
import re

txt = """Strawberries are fruit.
Do you like grape jelly?
She sings well.
Hershey's chocolate is delicious"""

pronouns = ['she', 'he', 'they']
c = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(pronouns) + r')\b', re.IGNORECASE)

for line in txt.splitlines():
    if c.search(line):
        print(line, " NOT A STATEMENT")
```

output:

```
She sings well.  NOT A STATEMENT
```

`\b` can correctly detects words if they are wrapped inside `',.|" and etc`.

with flag `re.IGNORECASE` you don't worry about `she` or `She` for example.

### Without Regex

```py
txt = """Strawberries are fruit.
Do you like grape jelly?
She sings well.
Hershey's chocolate is delicious"""

stripped_chars = ',."\'|'

pronouns = {'he', 'she', 'they'}

for line in txt.splitlines():
    lst = line.lower().split()
    stripped_and_lower = {word.strip(stripped_chars) for word in lst}
    if stripped_and_lower & pronouns:
        print(line, " NOT A STATEMENT")
```

output:

```
She sings well.  NOT A STATEMENT
```

explanation :

This way we will lower and split each line to get the words then we try to strip away `stripped_chars` characters from each word. Now we have just lower-case words. Because we used set-comprehension and we have `pronouns` as a set, we can do the set operation between them. if `stripped_and_lower & pronouns` is not empty, it mean that there is a pronouns in the line.

Comment: Checking on it. I'm still new to this function. Thank you!

Comment: I still don't get the re, compile, letter r. Do you mind if you can explain it to me?

Comment: @OmnerJamesCrisanto `re` is a regex module in Python. `compile` will compile a regex pattern into regex object. we use `r""` syntax to say this is a raw-string. This way Python will not escape characters inside the string. Try to run `print("\n")` and `print(r"\n")`. Because regular expression has a lot of of characters that have special meaning for Python, we will usually use raw-string for regex patterns.